bootstrap datepicker on wordpress custom post type custom template not showing up
I'm new to WordPress Plugin Development and I'm having some issues with custom post type where I have a custom template:
add_filter('single_template', array($this, 'customTemplate'));
    public function customTemplate($single)
    {

        global $post;

        /* Checks for single template by post type */
        if ($post->post_type == 'bestellung') {
            if (file_exists($this->plugin_path . '/templates/shop.php')) {
                return $this->plugin_path . '/templates/shop.php';
            }
        }

        return $single;
    }

and inside the shop.php:
<?php

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <!-- some html here... -->

    <div id="datepicker"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_input_datepicker_shop" name="hidden_input_datepicker_shop">

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({
                todayBtn: true,
                 clearBtn: true,
                 todayHighlight: true,
                 toggleActive: true,
                 startDate: '-d',
              });

              $('#datepicker').on('changeDate', function() {
                  $('#hidden_input_datepicker_shop').val(
                      $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
                   );
               });
           });
      </script>


<?php endwhile;
endif;
?>


I have enqueued the bootstrap datepicker css and js on a separate file
 // enqueue bootstrap datepicker
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'bootstrap_datepicker_css',
            $this->plugin_url . 'bootstrap-datepicker-1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css'
        );
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_datepicker_js', $this->plugin_url . 'bootstrap-datepicker-1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.9.0', true);

However, the datepicker does not show up on the custom template.
I tried enqueueing directly on the page template using cdn, but it did not work. I checked on the dev tools, it seems like the bootstrap datepicker is not lodaded.
// Enqueue Bootstrap Datepicker script
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-datepicker', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.9.0', true);

// Enqueue Bootstrap Datepicker CSS
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-datepicker-css', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css', array(), '1.9.0');


It works perfecly fine on the CPT admin page meta box but doesn't show up on the page template.

I also checked on the Network panel on dev tools. It seems like the bootstrap datepicker styles and script is not loaded in there. Whereas, it is properly loaded on the CPT Admin Page.

Update:
I added cdn links directly on the custom template and it works now.
<!-- bootstrap datepicker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha512-34s5cpvaNG3BknEWSuOncX28vz97bRI59UnVtEEpFX536A7BtZSJHsDyFoCl8S7Dt2TPzcrCEoHBGeM4SUBDBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha512-LsnSViqQyaXpD4mBBdRYeP6sRwJiJveh2ZIbW41EBrNmKxgr/LFZIiWT6yr+nycvhvauz8c2nYMhrP80YhG7Cw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

